# How to retrieve and send geolocation while app in background using cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    var callbackFn = function(location) {
    console.log('[js] BackgroundGeolocation callback:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);
```

This get code is not sending location when app is closed.I tried other method as well, but didn't get successful way to send location data to server.

```
    $.get('http://test.com/rotech/location.php?latitude=' + location.latitude);

    backgroundGeolocation.finish();
};

var failureFn = function(error) {
    console.log('BackgroundGeolocation error');
};


    backgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
    desiredAccuracy: 10,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 30,
    interval: 60000
});


    backgroundGeolocation.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify any error/stacktrace you are facing?

Comment: Rishab, I am not able to test the background gps. As it is sending the location when App is open. But when i close app, It doesn't.  So plz tell me how to test it so that i can know the real problem. And how to send location as well.

Comment: please have a look at this plugin [here](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)

Comment: Ok. thanks. I want to send dynamic user_id with location to database. How can i set dynamic user_id.